# How do you install Ratchet on Mac OSX?

Tags: php, macos, unix, installation, ratchet

I have spent hours trying to install Ratchet on my Mac, and I keep running into errors.  I'm following [this](http://socketo.me/docs/push) guide, as it is the perfect use case for my project.  I have run the composer installation and have successfully generated my composer.phar file in my working directory.  I have also created the composer.json file from the tutorial in that same directory.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
    }
}
```

I then cd into my working directory and run

```
$ php composer.phar install
```

This gives the following output:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - react/zmq v0.3.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
> - react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
> - Installation request for react/zmq 0.2.*|0.3.* -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.0, v0.3.0].

So, seeing this, I went to install React/ZeroMQ, but now both of THOSE are giving my installation problems.  I'm just plain lost at this point, I can never really tell when something has installed or not.  I've run a make and sudo make install for [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/docs:source-git), but I'm still seeing the same errors when I try to install Ratchet.

For [React](https://github.com/reactphp/react), I followed the installation guide in the readme, which was only one line.  But I'm not sure where this install is supposed to take place.  It doesn't seem to be global, so I think the location matters.

Can someone help point me in the right direction to get Ratchet installed?

Comment: Are you going to run this on OSX or is it just to have as a dev environment? If so I recommend you use a linux VM so you get the same environment as it will be hosted on, a bonus is that you can follow all writeups on how to install <something> on a well supported platform (ie ubuntu server). [Getting started with vagrant](https://box.scotch.io/)

Comment: I will look into getting a Linux VM

Answer (score 1):

I have done with the following steps

### Install with brew

- `brew install zmq`

### Make php-zmq

- `git clone git://github.com/mkoppanen/php-zmq.git`
- `cd php-zmq`
- `phpize && ./configure`
- `make && make install`

### Add extension to php.ini:

- Find php ini file `php --ini`
- add `extension=zmq.so`

.

#### Problem

*Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script*

#### Solution

`brew install autoconf`